# How do I install Windows drivers without having an internet connection

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, drivers, internet

I have two computers which I will name "**Goody**" and "**Baddy**"

**Baddy** is bad because:

1. **Baddy** cannot connect to the internet.
2. **Baddy** needs some Microsoft drivers installed.

Everything works fine on ***Goody***, including the internet connection.

***Baddy*** is running Windows 10 as its operating system.

My goal is to install some drivers made from Microsoft onto ***Baddy***.

---

#### What will ***NOT*** work

Everyone says to do the following on a different website (NOT stack exchange super user):

1. Open the Device Manager on ***Baddy***.
2. Select the category named "Network Adaptors"
3. Right click on Baddy's ethernet driver.
4. Choose the "update driver" option.
5. Choose the option to search the internet for the most up-to-date version of the driver.

**PROBLEM** : *Baddy* has no internet connection. If Baddy has version 1.42 of the ethernet driver, then Baddy cannot automatically search the internet for version 5.6 of the driver. ***Baddy*** has no internet connection.

---

#### My Plan:

1. Download the driver from Microsoft.com onto the good computer (***Goody***). Goody has no trouble connecting to the internet.
2. Use a thumb-drive to copy the driver from ***Goody*** onto ***Baddy***
3. Install the driver on ***Baddy***

**PROBLEM:**

It is very difficult to find device drivers for download on the Microsoft website. The Microsoft website says, "right click in the device manager and choose the automatic download option"

The whole automatic download thing is not going to work.

Where can I download Microsoft Newtwork device drivers?

How do I install the drivers onto the bad computer (***Baddy***)? Baddy has no internet connection.

Comment: Does Baddy have an internet connection? ;)

Answer (score 1):

**(A)** The Ethernet NIC is normally soldered to the motherboard. Find the manufacturer of the motherboard and get the NIC driver there  using the good machine and install the driver on the nonworking machine.

**(B)** Strongly consider a USB Wired NIC with drivers, and use that. You can install the drivers that accompany the USB NIC and then you should have Internet.

Such a USB Wired NIC can be use another time and on another machine as well.

Comment: Or use Goody, download the driver from there, place onto a USB stick, carry to Baddy, and install from usb stick.

Comment: And you can manually updated Windows driver from downloaded driver pack.
https://www.microcenter.com/tech_center/article/9024/how-to-manually-update-drivers-in-windows-10